# What kind of charged rifles could exist in a hard sci-fi future?

Tags: technology, science-fiction, weapons

Right so for a worldbuilding server I am part of I am making some weaponry. But now I got some test models done, I am unknown to what kindof weapons they are. The rp is set in 2150-2250. Not a solid date set yet. The weaponry in question does not contain any solid shot rounds but instead a canister with something I do not know the name off yet. I looked around at Lasers and Blasters, plasma isn't really something for me either.

The rest of my faction, with that ships and their weapons are Ion powered. I do got an explaination of those. But I don't just want to say that my ammunition is a canister of a certain size!

Is there anyone that could help me with an ammunition type? And what I would need for that?

Comment: Hello Acid, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. It's important to understand that SE is not a discussion forum. SE's basic model is one-specific-question/one-best-answer. As it is, you're inviting a brainstorming discussion with, frankly, no foundation upon which to work, and that's off-topic. We're delighted to help you bring your weapon into existence, but we won't invent the weapon for you. This Q is so vague that I don't even know where to start asking for details. I need to vote-to-close until we can make this a specific question.

Comment: I understand. I agree that my question is really fague. I read what Worldbuilding is about and I tried to give as much information as I could. But in the moment I was too worried I would strafe from the basics of my question. I'll make sure to take longer to make my next.

Comment: Thanks. It's not that it needs to be longer, what it needs to be is more focused, detailed, and objective. What are you trying to achieve? What rules in your world are involved? What limitations, restrictions, or conditions exist? What goals do you have? Open-ended, undefined-technology questions violate at least two of the "do not ask" bullets on the [help/dont-ask] list. We have a love-hate relationship with fishing-for-ideas questions. We know they're needed, but SE is completely not designed for them. (\*continued\*)

Comment: ...This puts an additional burden on you, the OP (original poster). You need to ask a question where a single best answer can be selected (even if you have no intention of selecting one). If you can't explain how you'll judge a best answer, the question isn't ready to be asked. Does that make sense?

Comment: It does, thank you. I've been on Reddit a bit so I know the basics of posting ig. I'm writing down some stuff in notepad to remember myself if that is alright. I do think I will ask some more questions as I never was able to find a site like this, I always ended up on wikipedia. And I got to admit it isn't the best place for Sci-fi.

Answer (score 4):

**Carbon dioxide**

**[image: Carbon dioxide.]**

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MrVW7uNecHo

Your gun is loaded with compressed CO2.  It is the future so a lot of it fits in the cylinder.  You can let it out in a measured way and make solid chunks of dry ice which is what they are doing in this video.  Those are your bullets.  You can use the same compressed CO2 to fire your rifle - it is like an air rifle or super paintball gun.

And it is all environmentally correct.  CO2 is captured from the atmosphere and pressurized using green energy.  Spent shots and used propellant sublimate back into the atmosphere.  It is the circle of life!  With some death.

---

Maybe you can say there is some argon in the compressed gas mix.  "Argon" sounds more scifi than dry ice paintball gun.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I'm impressed that out of my messy question you managed to get an answer. I'll look into it and start writing ;)

Comment: While this is a good idea, I'm not sure that the dry ice "bullets" would remain solid over longer distances.

Comment: @TheDaleks How long does it take for a dry ice pellet to sublimate?  How long for a bullet to fly?  I'm pretty sure such bullets would arrive solid; that's the least of your worries...

Answer (score -1):

**Water**

Water is polar and You can use magnetic field to speed it up to any needed speed. But mostly usefull as an anti human weapon small sized, easy to refill.

**Metals**

You can use liquid metal same way as water but need to store it in heated canister. And at this point can make it from non lethal anti-human to even planet destroyer size.

**Nanomachines**

You can use canister with nanomachines. Shot can be only machines, some kind of shell(or rocket) created in weapon up to whole canisters fired to target. Machines are nonreplicatable but can be programed any way You want. Example: can destroy clothes but not harm person, can be like a glue to prevent moves of target, can dissasemble molecular structure of armor on heavy armoured ship, can make cloud/net in space that catch ship and then move to engines to destroy thrusters. Nanomachines can have disadvantages like 1-5 steted programs for each canister and need load specific canister to do diffrent jobs but only border is your imagination(and phisic if You use it).